# Are function names stored inside of an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, identifier, iife

It is my understanding that the grouping operator around a function declaration forces the function to be evaluated as an expression. This is what allows the execution parentheses operator `()` to work. However, this approach removes the function name from being accessible outside itself. I'm wondering how IIFE function names are stored compared to function declaration names which are available in the scope they are declared.

```
(function hidden(){
    console.log("function executed");
})()
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the second piece of code?

Comment: "there is an error which states that hidden is an unexpected identifier." --- nope, the error message does not say that.

Comment: your second code block is not valid at all - and if you moved `hidden();` inside the `{}` you'd end up with too much recursion

Comment: if, on the other hand you moved `hidden()` outside the IIFE, then, of course, `hidden` is undefined, due to the scope of the named function expression - but the final `()` invokes the IIFE anyway, so why do you need to invoke it a second time?

Comment: Named function declarations are visible only inside of the function itself. The following works `(function a() { console.log(a()); return 'a'})`

Comment: Your second code sample does not have an IIFE per se (syntax error) because you are not wrapping the full contents in a function. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44651956/227299) so you can see how to make it an IIFE and then it will behave as I believe you intended

Answer (score 1):

There's a good article by Angus Croll about the difference between a function declaration and a function expression in javascript (https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/)

Basically what you're trying to do is treat the function hidden() as a function declaration *inside* of a function expression. As Croll states in the article, inside a function expression, "the function name (if any) is not visible outside of it’s scope (contrast with Function Declarations)."

If you rewrite the anonymous function as an assignment it makes the point clearer I think:

```
var a = function hidden() {
  console.log('inside hidden');
}
```

now this will error:

```
var a = function hidden() {
  console.log('inside hidden');
}
hidden();
```

because the name of the function is not available outside of its own context.

This however will work fine:

```
var a = function hidden() {
  console.log('inside hidden');
}
a();
```

since the variable can be referenced outside of its own context as you would expect (otherwise it wouldn't be reachable anywhere but inside the hidden() function body).

If we take a look again at the anonymous version you can see why it fails:

```
(function hidden() {
  console.log('inside hidden');
}
// We're outside of IIFEs function body here
// so NO code can be executed.
)();
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct, if you called the code where the comment is, wouldn't that be invalid?

I would have thought the whole lot would need to be wrapped in yet another function? otherwise (expression)() does nothing?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach yep I think we're both saying the same thing? Where that comment is in the last code snippet, you cannot execute the `hidden()` function.

Comment: I wouldn't think you can execute *anything* that didn't have a function as a return type?

Comment: The point @RyanTheLeach is making is valid, you cannot execute anything at that point (no matter if hidden would be defined elsewhere in the code), it would simply lead to the syntax error described by the OP. But for the rest, it's a good explanation

Comment: @Icepickle I see the point you guys are making. I wasn't confident that NO code could be executed outside of the function body in an IIFE.  There always seems to be some exception in javascript where what you think should happen is not the case. I've updated the comment to indicate that no code can be executed outside of the function body in an IIFE. Learned something new today!

Comment: Last answer's point is kinda correct, but no, `// so NO code can be executed` note is wrong. The parenthesis expression (or grouping operator) matches an enclosed expression which can be any of the language expressions, i.e., the comma operator (also called "sequence expression"), which consists of two expressions. Then, if a comma appears after the `}`, then it's the comma operator. An `+` token may also appear, among many other things, i.e. `(function a(){} >>> 5)`

Comment: Hope I'm not bothering

Comment: @Cloudiness not at all. Commas and plus signs make sense as they are essentially extending the same expression instead of starting execution of a new, entirely separate, expression. Trying to think of a good way to word that....I suppose I meant to say that no separate instructions could be executed after the closing bracket of the function body?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's simply a parsing/syntax error, as you said, *"unexpected identifier"*. You could fix this by using the comma operator: `(function hidden() { ... }, hidden())`, but the `hidden` name (holding the function object) from your function expression will be only available inside the function scope. You could solve this by doing a definition instead:

```
(function() {
    function hidden(){
        console.log("hidden");
    }
    hidden();
})();
```

You could also do bound definitions. Like...

ES4 ([reference interpreter](http://mediafire.com/file/a8rn9b642zv3hly/ES4.7z) builds):

```
{
    let function hidden()
    {
        console.log("hidden");
    }
    hidden();
}
```

ES6-based JavaScript

```
{
    let hidden = function()
    {
        console.log("hidden");
    }
    hidden();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of a function is available by accessing the function's name property:

IIFE:

```
(function hidden() {
    console.log("Function name is: '" + hidden.name + "'"); //Function name is: 'hidden'
})();
console.log(hidden.name);//Error because IIFEs have their own private scope.
```

function declaration:

```
function available(){
    return;
}
console.log(available.name);//"Available" - the console.log has access to the function's scope.
```

Answer (score -1):

On the other hand the following is perfectly valid:

```js
(two = function() {
  console.log('two');
}, 
console.log('one'), 
two)()
```

Comment: Well, you're creating a global variable. -1 Yeah, you're making it an expression instead of a declaration, if you add better explanation, I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

You have a syntax error because

```
(function hidden(){
    console.log("hidden");
}
hidden();)
```

is not an expression but

```
(function hidden(){
    console.log("hidden");
})
```

is an expression that returns the function itself and you call it with `()`.

You could make it an expression by adding a comma between the two parts, and removing the semi-colon. However, `hidden` would be only defined within the function itself and you couldn't call it. That's called a [named function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression)

```
// Uncaught ReferenceError: hidden is not defined
(function hidden(){
    console.log("hidden");
},
hidden())
```

You probably meant to do the following

```
(function() {
    function hidden(){
        console.log("hidden");
    }
    hidden();
})()
```

In that case, you are creating a function declaration that is visible within the containing IIFE